# Read a rtf file and filter out all headline and subtitle elements

Tags: python, rtf

I have a Google document that has a lot of headlines and subtitles in addition to its text. Using python I want to read the rtf of the document and afterward use do my own process with the resulting text.

How do I import the rtf?

Answer (score 0):

I did cursory PyPI research and I was not unable to find tool, which would do what you want. If you are allowed to change your approach, so you convert rtf to plain text first, then [striprtf](https://pypi.org/project/striprtf/) should be helpful. If this is not allowed then you would need to examine your files and then implement code which detect *groups* to delete, before doing that comprehend [syntax of Rich Text File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format#Code_syntax). Observe that Rich Text Files are text files (not binary files) so you should be able to investigate it using text editor e.g. Notepad++.

Comment: If I convert to plain text, then how do I know what text is headlines and which isn't?